# Varying output in simulator and iPad device

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

i am facing rather weird problem.. I am developing a educational app on iphone. The output keeps varying from simulator to Device.. i am geting  the exact output on simulator. But, i am unable to see certain images after transferring it to the Device... The output also varies interms of spacing between some icons.... I have all the icons available in the resources folder. i have also cleaned the build and reinstalled it many times.....
 Can anybody please help me regarding this issue... Your advices will help me in my project.. Thank you...

Comment: It would be help if you could show us the code snippet that's misbehaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the images, is it a case sensitivity problem? On the device, the file system is case sensitive, so when you're loading an image with imageNamed: or whatever, you have to get the case of the filename correct. That isn't the case in the simulator.

Comment: Thank you amorya.... it worked well for me... But there is some problem with the ipa file now.... the app works fine when i install it directly from the system on to the device.But the output varies  when i upload the app into the device through a ipa file(filename.ipa)  i.e,from itunes... can you please help me with this....